# Merge selector CSS (Node/Ruby)

Tags: css, media-queries

I am looking for a tool (NodeJS or Ruby for example) that allow myself to merge my CSS selectors.

The site offers the option [minifyCSS](http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor/) but it is not optimal because I will depend on the site.

The idea of ​​merging the selectors would especially for my media queries.

Do you know what kind of plug-in ?

Thank you all :)

Update example:

```
.mon-module-1 {
    background: red;

    @media #{$medium-up} {
        background: orange;
        padding: 3rem;
    }

}

.mon-module-2 {
    background: blue;

    @media #{$medium-up} {
        background: grey;
        border: 1px red solid;
        padding: 3rem 1rem;
    }
}
```

Compiled:

```
@media (blablabla) {

    .mon-module-1 {
        background: orange;
        padding: 3rem;
    } 
}

@media (blablabla) {

    .mon-module-2 {
        background: grey;
        border: 1px red solid;
        padding: 3rem 1rem;
    }
}
```

What I want:

```
@media (blablabla) {
    .mon-module-1 {
        background: orange;
        padding: 3rem;
    }

    .mon-module-2 {
        background: grey;
        border: 1px red solid;
        padding: 3rem 1rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to give us an example.

Comment: I've update my first post :)

Comment: Compiled by what/whom? Can you describe in words the process you hope to accomplish?

Comment: Compiled with Compass. I would like compile with merged selector CSS :)

Comment: Your "compiled" version and "want this" version are semantically identical. So what's the point?